# Wait for ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a requirement where where my customers fetch some data from the database ..but it so happens sometimes the data is not available but gets available in say 5 to 6 minutes... so i want that until the user doesnt gets a reply the process should go on and on.. i know a timeout will do my job but is there another way to do it?

```
$.ajax({
          url: "checkStatus.php",
          success: function(msg){
          }
});

}
```

And the php file has a mysql query which checks status if its 1 it echo's some data... but i want the user to wait until it gets 1....  i can late kill the process if the time goes beyond 10 minutes

Comment: You're expecting a user to sit around for up to 10 minutes waiting? They'll do something else, and perhaps your script won't be permitted to complete. If you don't get the data you want immediately, tell the user that and give them an option to come back in ten minutes.

Comment: it is a sms shortcode service.. where a particular server url is hit when the user sends a message... and when he sends that message that is the time he gets the response... rather to verify his phone number...